# Laravel 5.8 Model whereJsonContains returning only exact matches

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

Laravel: 5.8

I'm currently having some issues with my `whereJsonContains` query. I'm trying to search an object and if the string is an exact match or partial match I get results, at the moment I am only getting exact matches.

```
$quote->whereJsonContains( 'quotes->current' , [ 'quote' => $request->input( 'quote' ) ] );
```

I've removed the unnecessary code as this is part of a search filter. The rest is working perfectly, but I can't seem to find anything in the docs about this or any working examples.

Example of json object in DB:

```
{
    "current": [
      {
        "quote": "This is a test quote 1",
        "page": "7",
        "who": "Nancy Harris",
        "explanation": "This is a text explanation about quote 1",
        "tags": "test1, testing, test",
        "created": "2019-10-30T00:38:20.414818Z",
        "updated": "2019-10-30T00:38:20.414826Z"
      },
      {
        "quote": "This is a test quote 2",
        "page": "60",
        "who": "Agnes Bates",
        "explanation": "This is a text explanation about quote 2",
        "tags": "test1, testing, test",
        "created": "2019-10-30T00:38:20.414818Z",
        "updated": "2019-10-30T00:38:20.414826Z"
      },
      {
        "quote": "This is a test quote 3",
        "page": "11",
        "who": "Wayne Griffin",
        "explanation": "This is a text explanation about quote 3",
        "tags": "test1, testing, test",
        "created": "2019-10-30T00:38:20.414818Z",
        "updated": "2019-10-30T00:38:20.414826Z"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried passing the quote as string as the second param? `$quote->whereJsonContains('quotes->current', request( 'quote'));`

Comment: Nah I figured it wouldn't work or be working off the wrong value.

Answer (score 0):

Try to extend to your qoute data.

```
$quote->whereJsonContains( 'quotes->current->qoute' ,'like', request('quote'));
```

Comment: He asked for exact matches.

Comment: @DilipHirapara nope, base on his question: but I also need to to return partial results as if I was using the LIKE operator

Comment: Yes I am only getting exact matches, I need partial as well. Will give this a try.

Comment: No luck, this causes invalid sql. SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%we% json_contains(`quotes`, ?, '$."current"."quote"')' at line 1"

Comment: @Second2None did you try removing the percent sign?

Comment: Yeah it returned a similar error:

message: "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'json_contains(`quotes`, ?, '$."current"."quote"')' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `quotes` where we json_contains(`quotes`, "LIKE", '$."current"."quote"'))"